# Backload FileHandler not found

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, jquery-file-upload, backload

I'm trying to use jQuery File Upload with Backload as a handler in an ASP.NET website, but can't get it to work.

This is the Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
<script src="js/uploader.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="fileupload" type="file">
</body> 
</html>
```

And the js to enable the file upload plugin:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var handlerUrl = "/Backload/FileHandler";

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: handlerUrl
    });
});
```

I have installed Backload using NuGet, and loaded jQuery File Upload into my project. All the references are loading fine (no errors in the console). When I try to upload a file I get an error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, and the resource noted is `http://localhost:61076/Backload/FileHandler`.

What am I missing here?

NOTE: I did not write any of this code. These are all copy\paste examples from the relevant sources, as I'm trying to get a basic thing working before actually building my own website.

Comment: You should better start with the demo solution package: https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/releases/download/v2.0.0.0/Backload.Standard.2.0.Full.zip

Answer (score 2):

Just saw that you have a ASP.NET WebForms project. Backload uses MVC by default. There are 2 ways to get Backload running in a classic WebForms projects:

- Add MVC NuGet packages to the project and add a route in RegisterRoutes()
- Or, add and register (Web.Config) an HttpHandler. Here you can delete the controller in "~/Backload/Controller" to avoid MVC dependencies.

Simpliest way is to add the MVC NuGet package and configure a route in "~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs":

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

The second solution (add an HttpHandler) is shown here:
https://github.com/blackcity/Backload/tree/master/Examples/Backload.Standard.2.0.Full/Backload.Demo/Other/Handler

Example:

```
public class FileHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// File handler demo for classic Asp.Net or HTML. 
    /// To access it in an Javascript ajax request use: <code>var url = "/Handler/FileHandler.ashx";</code>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// NOTE. Edit the web.config file to allow the DELETE method in the system.webServer.handlers section
    /// </remarks>
    public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            // Wrap the request into a HttpRequestBase type
            HttpRequestBase request = new HttpRequestWrapper(context.Request);


            // Create and initialize the handler
            IFileHandler handler = Backload.FileHandler.Create();
            handler.Init(request);


            // Call the execution pipeline and get the result
            IBackloadResult result = await handler.Execute();


            // Write result to the response and flush
            ResultCreator.Write(context.Response, result);
            context.Response.Flush();

        }
        catch
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: your detailed answer is very much appreciated! Will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you miss "r" in  FileHandler action name
http://localhost:61076/Backload/FileHandler

Comment: Oh dear. I wish that was the problem :) That's just a mistake I did while trying to figure out the problem. Corrected it to FileHandler and it still doesn't work (same result).